# Consul for assigning tasks to workers

Tags: consul

I'm wondering whether Consul can be used to assign commands to run workers.

I have one Dockerfile from which I can run all my commands, but there are ~150 commands that need to be run. Is it possible for me to use Consul to store these 150 different commands and for the workers to connect to Consul to work out which of the commands to run?

I'm new to Consul, and there are a lot of different possible applications, so any help would be helpful.

A command would look like this:

```
 celery -A functions worker --loglevel=INFO
```